# How do you import sagemath in Google Colaboratory?

Tags: python, sage, google-colaboratory

Can I have an example of how to import sagemath in Google Colaboratory? This doesn't work:

```
!pip install sage
from sage.all import *
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sage isn't just a `pip`-installable package; there's currently no easy way to use sage directly from Colab.

(Note that the `pip install sage` command above is installing a [completely different package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sage); there's also a [sagemath package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sagemath), but that doesn't include all the components of sage.)

Answer (score 7):

Until Google Colaboratory provides SageMath, there are various
ways to use SageMath online and/or to collaborate on SageMath
worksheets:

- [SageCell](http://sagecell.sagemath.org/) -- for one-off computations
- [CoCalc](https://cocalc.com) -- "Collaborative Calculation in the cloud"
  -- has its own worksheet format (.sagews) and its own implementation
  of Jupyter notebooks; both allow collaboration and sharing, and support
  a variety of compute engines besides SageMath
- [Binder](https://mybinder.org); see also

  - [sage-binder-env: a SageMath-based computing environment for binder](https://github.com/sagemath/sage-binder-env/) -- based on work of the
    [OpenDreamKit Horizon 2020 European Research Infrastructures project (#676541)](http://opendreamkit.org).

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

1. installing conda in colab
2. within conda installing sage

Problems:

1. at the start of each cell where you want to use sage you have to use this:

```
    %%bash
    source activate sage
```

2. effectively, this "solution" only enables to use sage within colab, it is definitely not a proper full solution

Installation:

```
    !pip install -q condacolab
    import condacolab
    condacolab.install()
    !conda create -n sage sage python=X  # X is version of python, for instance 3.9
```

Now make your program

```
%%bash
source activate sage
sage -c '
YOUR CODE HERE
'
```

Comment: This answer needs more information. "installing conda ..." is not completely explained

Comment: @PerroNoob, the installation information for conda is provided several lines later.

Comment: If I misunderstood you, please provide me more info about what explanation do you want.